# Trouble finding core dump in Ubuntu 18.04, in application built from source

Tags: crash, apport

I have turned on the `apport` service, and set `ulimit` to `unlimited`. The application (`emacs` version 27.1.50, built from source from the `emacs-27` branch) reports that a core is dumped. However, I can't find it. I've looked in `/var/crash`, the current working directory, and the directory from which `emacs` was invoked, and there are no recently created files there. I also looked at all files anywhere on the hard drive for files created in the last hour, and found nothing relevant. The `find` command did turn up contents of `/var/crash` supposedly meeting those criteria, but their timestamps are from months ago, and pertain to other applications:

```
$ ls -l /var/crash/
total 1508
-rw-r----- 1 root     whoopsie  244060 Apr 23  2221 _lib_systemd_systemd-logind.0.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie    2233 Apr 20  2221 linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic.147326.crash
-rw-r----- 1 ubuntu   whoopsie 1290587 Aug 27 11:27 _usr_bin_lxpanel.1000.crash
```

```
$ sudo service --status-all | grep apport
 [ + ]  apport
```

Command used to search the full drive:

```
sudo find / -type f -cmin -60 | grep -v '^/proc/' | grep -v '^/sys/' | grep -v '^/home/ubuntu/\.cache' | grep -v '^/home/ubuntu/.mozilla' | grep -v '^/home/ubuntu/\.config/chromium'
```

```
$ sysctl kernel.core_pattern
kernel.core_pattern = |/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E
```

However, a [test for apport functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18428730/1941213) does work:

```
$ sleep 10 & killall -SIGSEGV sleep
[3] 11705
$ ls
[3]+  Segmentation fault      (core dumped) sleep 10
$ ls /var/crash/ | grep sleep
_bin_sleep.1000.crash
```

That suggests to me that a key factor here could be that `emacs` is built from non-debian source, and is missing some kind integration expected by `apport`.